# Measuring the Performance of SIP servlet container based on the load

Tags: performance, sip, latency, response-time, mobicents-sip-servlets

I have a simple sip servlet application, based on this scenario:

[image]

and I deploy it on a servlet container like Mobicents. Now, I want to send requests from a client to this application and I'm gonna to do this by [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/).

What I want to measure is the latency between the sending of INVITE(1) request and receiving the 200(8) response.

I want to know how the latency changes with the increasing the load per second.

How can I measure the latency(response time) to the load generated by the SIPp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at response times see http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#Statistics.

FYI, Mobicents SIP Servlets already contains a number of performance examples see https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/tree/master/sip-servlets-test-suite/sipp-scenarios/performance (they may need a bit of cleanup though)